# laravel unique validation when updating record

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm using Laravel for my web application and have a 'mobile' field that I want to update. I'm using the following validation rule:

```
'mobile' => ['required', Rule::unique('operators')->ignore(/* unsure what to put here */)]
```

I want to update the mobile number, but I need to ignore the unique validation for the 'mobile' field if the requested mobile number is the same as the one currently in the database for the authenticated user. In other words, users should be allowed to keep their current mobile number without triggering the unique validation error.

Could someone please guide me on how to achieve this in Laravel? Any help or code examples would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: you need to provide the primary key of the row that should be ignored, something like: `Rule::unique('operators')->ignore($this->route('id'))]` if your request is like: `operators/{id}`

Comment: Although [`this`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#:~:text=Forcing%20A%20Unique%20Rule%20To%20Ignore%20A%20Given%20ID) way should work, why not define your own custom validation rule then?

Comment: `$mobile = $this->mobile;
        $operator = Operator::firstWhere('mobile',$mobile);
        return [
            'first_name'=>'required',
            'last_name'=>'required',
            'signature'=>['required', 'exists:App\Models\File,_id'],
            'province_id'=>'required',
            'address'=>'required',
            'form_ids'=>'required|array',
            'mobile'=>[ 'required', Rule::unique('operators', 'mobile')->ignore($operator->id)]`
        ];
i have tried this but still doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'mobile' => ['required', Rule::unique('operators')->ignore($operator->id)]
```